# How to extract a GUID from a binary packet in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, serialization, marshalling

I have a object containing multiple variables in C# that is marshaled to binary format and sent over a socket connection to a C++ application. The c++ application receives the binary data in the format of TArray < uint8 >. One of the fields that was serialized in C# is a GUID. I am trying to deserialize the the packet and populate a C++ GUID.

First I load the binary data using a memory reader and going to the byte location where the GUID field should be:

```
FMemoryReader FromBinary = FMemoryReader(TheBinaryArray, true);
FromBinary.Seek(9);
```

The GUID field should be 16 bytes in the binary. So I create a 16 byte field in c++

```
uint32 Data[4];
```

and populate the data

```
FromBinary << Data[0];
FromBinary << Data[1];
FromBinary << Data[2];
FromBinary << Data[3];
```

create a new GUID

```
GUID guid;
```

Now I dont know how to populate the GUID with the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GUID` does not consist of 4 `uint32` values.  It consists of 1 `uint32`, 2 `uint16`, and 8 `uint8` values.

You can copy the *raw bytes* from the array into the `GUID` variable (why are you using `uint32 Data[4]` instead of `uint8 Data[16]`?).  You can use `memcpy()` or `CopyMemory()` for that, eg:

```
GUID guid;
memcpy(&guid, &Data[0], 16);
//CopyMemory(&guid, &Data[0], 16);
```

Or you can simply type-cast the memory address of the first byte in the array to a `GUID*` and then dereference the pointer and assign it to the `GUID` variable:

```
GUID guid;
guid = *((GUID*)&Data[0]);
```

Or, simply get rid of the array altogether and read the bytes from the memory reader into the `GUID` variable directly (if you are able to pass a `void*` pointer to the reader and not an array).